# Facebook FQL. Can't get list of eid(s) from event_member

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get event information from a fan page, but running into troubles just getting ANYTHING out of the event_member db.

I can get proper information out of the event DB with;
query: 'SELECT eid, name, tagline, pic_small,host, description, start_time, creator FROM event WHERE eid=EVENTIDNUMBER'

but to get the eid(s)
query: 'SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=1289767016'

returns nothing.

I really really need this to work.  I can;t seem to get anywhere with Facebook, and am feeling very unhappy with my commiment to make somthing work with FB.

ANy help is greatley welcomed.

TBR

Comment: I am really lost.  Any method to return a list of events is welcomed.

Comment: are you sure that the user (uid) in where clause actually has events at first place?

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify permissions for events list

```
<fb:login-button perms="user_events,friends_events"></fb:login-button>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,user_events,friends_events&state=". $_SESSION['state'];
```

I use scope with user_events and friends_events.

But the query doesn't work.

My query is (after set scope permission):

```
$dataGo = mktime(0,0,0,06,01,2012);
$fql = "SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = '1301241847' AND rsvp_status = 'attending' AND start_time > '" . $dataGo . "'";
```